# The time interval from the chart highcharts

Tags: highcharts

[jsFiddle](http://vk.cc/3H1YUX)

The time interval is now on it is this:

[image]

How to make that interval was 30 seconds?

[image]

My manipulation API highcharts lead to failure, it turns out, but the area is expanding, and only 30 seconds you'll see next time, then something else.

I hope that there are experts on such issues.

Comment: Assume the link to your jsfiddle is down, or blocked by a firewall. Your question makes no sense without it. Could you please post the relevant parts in your question (leave the link as it gives more context for the interested reader) so we can help you? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set your `tickInterval` to 30 seconds.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/s2ujt7fv/2/

The reason that only one axis tick and label are showing up is that you don't have enough data points to show more than one, with 30 seconds between.

Add more data, and it works as you would expect:

- http://jsfiddle.net/em3k1da8/